# Counting unique occurrences of specific strings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to achieve something which I know has to be simple, but I have not had success finding a solution for. My problem is simple. I am trying to count the occurrences of "Bad" or "Good" under each column in a simple table, but only once:

[image: simple table]

For example, a value of "Bad" under column A should be counted only once regardless of how many occurrences of "Bad" are under column A.

The closest I have gotten to achieving this outcome was with
`=COUNTIF(G2:G9,UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad"),,TRUE))`

This formula achieves my goal of working with mixed strings in a column. It will correctly count only "Bad"

[[image: It will correctly count only "Bad"],](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7zFa.png)

But if more than one occurrence of "Bad" is present it incorrectly returns a value of `0`:

[image: returns a value of 0]

Removing `TRUE` from the formula, and ending up with `=COUNTIF(G2:G9,UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad")))` instead of fixing the problem it introduces a new problem of it counting multiple occurrences of the string "Bad" more than once:

[image: more than once]

Can someone advise me on what I am doing wrong, or if what I want to do is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what form the results should take, but the easiest way to get it is (in my opinion) with the following formula (in `A9` to copy):

```
=--ISNUMBER(MATCH($F9,A$1:A$8,0))
```

As illustrated.
[image: Bad/Good]

Answer (score 0):

The formulas listed in your OP isn't working for the following reasons:

For approach using:

```
=COUNTIF(G2:G9,UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad"),,1))
```

---

- Using : `FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad")` returns `Bad` twice from the range.
- Using `UNIQUE()`: On wrapping the `UNIQUE()` function in the above formula returns `#VALUE!` error this is because of the last parameter used in the said function that is to return `TRUE -- Return items that appear exactly once` where as it is returning two similar values. **Side Note:** --> `TRUE` and `1` means same and `O` and `FALSE` refers to same.
- Using `COUNTIF()` : On wrapping with `COUNTIF()` it returns `0` because you are trying to find `#VALUE!` error in the range hence the output as `0`.
- Using without the `TRUE`: It returns `2` because it matches the values with the range as the array returned using `FILTER()` shows `{"Bad";"Bad"}` on wrapping the `UNIQUE()` it returns only one single `Bad` as criteria to find in the range `G2:G9`.

---

Suggested to use the following formula which would work accordingly as per requested:

[image]

---

Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,1-ISNA(XMATCH(G2:G9,{"Bad","Good"}))))<>""))
```

---

In the above formula i have included both the criteria `Bad` & `Good` as well to return the required output. However, if only `Bad` is needed then,

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad"))<>""))
```

---

Another alternative method is to use :

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(G2:G9,G2:G9="Bad")))
```

---

Or, this will be bit shorter one as well:

For both `Good` and `Bad`

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(G2:G9)={"Bad","Good"}))
```

---

For only `Bad`

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(G2:G9)="Bad"))
```

---

Or for the whole range using `LAMBDA()` helper function called `BYCOL()`

[image]

---

For Both `Good` and `Bad`

```
=BYCOL(G2:K9,LAMBDA(α, SUM(N(UNIQUE(α)={"Bad","Good"}))))
```

---

For Only `Bad`

```
=BYCOL(G2:K9,LAMBDA(α, SUM(N(UNIQUE(α)="Bad"))))
```

---